# Confused with paths running jekyll website locally

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

I host my website on GitHub Pages so I used `site.github.url` in my URL's (as it is described in documentation). Like this:

```
<a href="{{ page.url | prepend: site.github.url }}">{{ page.title }}</a>
```

in documentation it is also said that

> This way you can preview your site locally from the site root on localhost, but when GitHub generates your pages from the gh-pages branch all the URLs will resolve properly.

Now I try to preview it locally, but all the links have `http://my-username.github.io/` in front of them.

What am I doing wrong? Maybe I am missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Locally you can use a `_config_local.yml` to override default URL value.

Add this in your `_config_local.yml`:

```
github:
  url: http://localhost:4000
```

And then you can launch Jekyll and ask to parse both config files like this:

```
bundle exec jekyll build --config _config.yml, _config_local.yml
```

and

```
bundle exec jekyll serve --config _config.yml,_config_local.yml
```

Optional: You can alias the command or use `rake` to launch tasks.

Add the `rake` gem to your `Gemfile`:

```
group :development do
  gem 'rake'
end
```

Install with `bundle install`

Create a `Rakefile`:

`touch Rakefile`

Copy this content in your `Rakefile`:

```
require 'jekyll'

task :build do

options = {
  'trace'       => true,
  'verbose'     => true,
  'config' => %w(_config.yml _config_local.yml)
}
Jekyll::Commands::Build.process(options)
end

task :serve do
options = {
  'serving'     => true,
  'watch'       => true,
  'incremental' => true,
  'config'      => %w(_config.yml _config_local.yml)
}
Jekyll::Commands::Build.process(options)
Jekyll::Commands::Serve.process(options)
end
```

Now you can use `bundle exec rake build` and `bundle exec rake serve` without having to pass options.